# How to create generic class accepts multiple types C#

Tags: c#, reflection

I have two classes:

```cs
LinkedEntityProvider<TObj, TRes> and HistValidator<TObj>.
```

In the second you need to create an instance of the first.

```cs
PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(TObj).GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
{
    var sourceAttrs = prop.GetCustomAttribute<Reference>();

    if (sourceAttrs != null)
    {
        Type entityType = sourceAttrs.ReferenceType;

        //Here i need to create LinkedEntityProvider<TObj, TRes> and use type entityType like TRes
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to create one using reflection? (Your response does not answer this question)

Comment: I gues. In second class i have one generic type, and i  have some code that generate the second type. And i need create instance of LinkedEntityProvider<TObj, TRes>

Comment: I see. Is TRes the `entityType` variable?

Comment: Yes. That type i need in second class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To construct a closed generic type, you can do this:

```
var openGenericType = typeof(LinkedEntityProvider<,>);
var closedGenericType = openGenericType.MakeGenericType(typeof(TObj), entityType);
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(closedGenericType);
```

The first line gets the open type, i.e. without generic parameters. We then supply the parameters to `MakeGenericType` to produce something similar to `typeof(LinkedEntityProvider<TObj, TRes>)`.

Once we have this, we can create an instance using `Activator.CreateInstance`. If the object constructor takes any parameters, you'll have to pass them to `Activator.CreateInstance`, for example:

```
var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(closedGenericType, new object[] { constructorParameter1, constructorParameter2 });
```

Note that, because there's no way of knowing the type that is produced at compile time, `Activator.CreateInstance` returns `object`.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it